# How to Configure GCC Global Defaults , Global Environment Variable and How to use them correctly

Tags: bash, shell, gcc, makefile, environment-variables

Where in Debian can I find make.conf.

I do want to type following directives each time I compile.
Is there anyway to automatically set them or add them or use them during compilation.

```
–-host=i686-w64-mingw32
–-build=i686-w64-mingw32
--target=i686-w64-mingw32
--CROSS_COMPILE=i686-w64-mingw32
--cross-prefix=i686-w64-mingw32
--prefix=i686-w64-mingw32
-march=core2
-mtune=native
-j2
```

What is the difference between the following :

```
CARCH and ARCH
HOST and  CHOST
CFLAGS and HOSTCLAG
CC and CHOSTCC
```

Which one is used when ?

In which files make and gcc environment variable,
global environment variable and path
bash environment variable and path are saved and where are they located.

How to set `__MAKE_CONF=` in debian .

How to change GCC and MAKE defaults, and set new defaults.

What is the difference between `CONCURRENCY_LEVEL` and `MAKEFLAGS`.

Comment: One question at a time please.

Comment: you can define those directive in one file, use `include` directive of Makefile to quote that file.

Comment: @gzh can you give some example ?